# Injecting a Master page into a Master-Detail page using XAML & Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a master detail page in XAML where both the Master and Detail pages without any concretions. I've got something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
      MasterPage
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    DetailPage
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

I'm using MVVM architecture and want it such that the 'MasterPage' is obtained from from ViewModel where I can switch it.

My view model is similar to this

```
public class MainPageViewModel : NavigableViewModel, IMainPageViewModel
{

    public MainPageModel MainPageViews { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel() : base()
    {

        MainPageViews = new MainPageModel()
        {
          NavigationBarPage = ViewFactory.Instance.Resolve<IMasterPageViewModel>()
        };
    }
}`
```

Is there anyway to bind the content page to a page in the ViewModel?

Comment: It seems that neither the Master property or Detail property of a MasterDetailPage are bindable properties. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing comment above to answer since there has been no activity on this since:

It seems that neither the Master property or Detail property of a MasterDetailPage are bindable properties. See: developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPag‌​e